how to freeze a yolov8 model and train it separately with pytorch lightining?
So i want to take a yolov8 classification model, freeze the layers and train it for a multilabel classification task, i changed the last layer and added a sigmoid activation function. but when i try to fit the model on my dataset it trains on imagenet instead.
is there a specific parameter that turns off this behaviour?
here is a part of my code.
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch.nn as nn


class MultilabelYOLO(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_labels):
        super(MultilabelYOLO, self).__init__()
        # load pretrained classification model
        self.base_model = YOLO("yolov8n-cls.pt")
        
        # Access the final layer of the base model
        self.base_model.model.model[-1] = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1280),
            nn.SiLU(inplace=True),
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=True),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(1280, num_labels),
            nn.Sigmoid() 
        )

    def freeze_layer(trainer):
        model = trainer.model
        num_freeze = 10
        print(f"Freezing {num_freeze} layers")
        freeze = [f'model.{x}.' for x in range(num_freeze)]  # layers to freeze 
        for k, v in model.named_parameters(): 
            v.requires_grad = True  # train all layers 
            if any(x in k for x in freeze): 
                print(f'freezing {k}') 
                v.requires_grad = False 
        print(f"{num_freeze} layers are freezed.")

    def forward(self, x):
        self.base_model.eval()
        self.base_model.add_callback("on_train_start", self.freeze_layer)
        return self.base_model(x)


